# Trouble Extracting Recording URLs from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and I have a requirement to parse all the recording URL from a website. I tried the below program but it's not able to find the recording links but It's printing other links in the web page. I am not aware of the website design, I tried with AI tools and Stackoverflow but I can find same solution every where. Can you please provide what is the mistake I am doing here or some other way I need to follow to parse this?

​

Sample recording URL which I found from the webpage using inspect element:

https://www.vector.com/int/en/events/global-de-en/webinar-recordings/7307e0a9000c63ad7dce5523ec058af2-remote-diagnostics-and-flashing

[image]
​

​

Here is the code snipper I tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

def parse_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    for quote in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
        href = quote.get('href')
        print(href)

base_url = 'https://www.vector.com/int/en/search/#type=%5B%22webinar_recording%22%5D&page=1&pageSize=50&sort=date&order=desc'
parse_page(base_url)
```

Comment: _" it's not able to find the recording links"_ -> the page has dynamic content, JS generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded via Javascript, sou BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. To simulate this requests you can try:

```py
import requests

payload = {
    "aggs": {
        "categories": {
            "terms": {"field": "downloadType", "order": {"_key": "asc"}, "size": 1000}
        },
        "content_type": {
            "terms": {"field": "type", "order": {"_key": "asc"}, "size": 1000}
        },
        "file_type": {
            "terms": {"field": "fileType", "order": {"_key": "asc"}, "size": 1000}
        },
        "languages": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "categoryFileLanguageDefaultLang",
                "order": {"_key": "asc"},
                "size": 1000,
            }
        },
        "products": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "categoryProductDefaultLang",
                "order": {"_key": "asc"},
                "size": 1000,
            }
        },
        "standards": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "categoryStandardDefaultLang",
                "order": {"_key": "asc"},
                "size": 1000,
            }
        },
        "topics": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "categoryTopicDefaultLang",
                "order": {"_key": "asc"},
                "size": 1000,
            }
        },
    },
    "explain": False,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "boost_mode": "multiply",
            "functions": [{"filter": {"match": {"type": "products"}}, "weight": 50}],
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "type": {
                                    "boost": 1,
                                    "operator": "AND",
                                    "query": "webinar_recording",
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must_not": {"exists": {"field": "endtime"}}
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {"range": {"endtime": {"gte": "now"}}},
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must_not": {
                                                "exists": {"field": "starttime"}
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {"range": {"starttime": {"lte": "now"}}},
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                    "must_not": [
                        {"term": {"type": {"value": "marketingitems"}}},
                        {"match": {"downloadType": {"query": "demos"}}},
                        {"match": {"downloadType": {"query": "software"}}},
                        {"match": {"downloadType": {"query": "drivers"}}},
                        {"match": {"downloadType": {"query": "freeware"}}},
                        {"match": {"downloadType": {"query": "service"}}},
                    ],
                    "should": [],
                }
            },
            "score_mode": "first",
        }
    },
    "size": 50,
    "sort": [{"sortdate": "desc"}],
    "suggest": {
        "didYouMean": {
            "phrase": {
                "direct_generator": [
                    {"field": "didYouMean.trigram", "suggest_mode": "always"}
                ],
                "field": "didYouMean.trigram",
                "gram_size": 3,
                "size": 5,
            },
            "text": "",
        }
    },
}

api_url = "https://search.vector.com/int-en/_search/"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"
}

data = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=payload).json()
for h in data["hits"]["hits"]:
    print(h["_source"]["title"])
    print(h["_source"]["streamingUrl"])
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Simplify the Simulation, Testing and Measurement of 10BASE-T1S Networks With CANoe/CANalyzer
https://vector-group.webex.com/vector-group/ldr.php?RCID=0ce68a6a7132fb032088f53a6b5cd4b2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Remote Diagnostics and Flashing
https://vector-group.webex.com/vector-group/ldr.php?RCID=7307e0a9000c63ad7dce5523ec058af2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Maintain ODX-based Diagnostic Data Easily, Quickly and Effectively with ODXStudio
https://vector-group.webex.com/vector-group/ldr.php?RCID=4c3f1a4d894482e9899b2c0a64f1914b
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems parsing this kind of websites is not easy for the newbies, I will check how to parse JS. In the website I have many pages to parse and the above script is working fine for the first page, can you please suggest how can I parse the second page, Do I need to change the payload?

Comment: @goodman In your browser, open Web Developer Tools -> Network tab and load the second page. You should see the API URL + payload there...

Comment: Got it. I will check it, but for the time being I changed size from 50 to 500 and now I can able to parse all the URL's. Once again Thank you.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely is there a way to get the `payload`, or information about it, just from pure python, ie no browser tools?